# I'm loading a menu from another subdomain (using jquery) and I need the relative links to be for the other subdomain - how do I do that?

Tags: jquery, relative-path

This is a variation on a theme. I looked at some other answers and they don't quite fit the bill.

I have `d1.site.org` and `d2.site.org`. d2 is using the following jquery to get the menu from d1: `$('#myNav').load('https://d1.site.org/ header');` but the relative links in the menu brought in from d1 all point to d2, and I want those links to become `d1.site.org/menu1` instead of what they now do which is `d2.site.org/menu1` (and end up w/ 404 errors).

PS - have CORS enabled, and the top level menu options come through ok and show correctly on d2, it's just the links contained levels below end up w/ the wrong subdomain. How do I make all the relative links point back to d1 when they're showing on d2?

Edit: to clarify - all of the menu links are `menu1`  `menu2` etc. on d1, which makes them `d1.site.org/menu1` etc. but when they are on d2, they are  `d2.site.org/menu1`, and I want them to be `d1.site.org/menu1`

Answer (score 1):

That's an absolute path, relative wouldn't have your domain in it. You can parse out the relative path and prefix it with the domain you do want.

```
    thing = 'd2.site.org/menu1';
    relative = thing.substring(thing.indexOf('.org')+4, thing.length);
    newLink = 'd1.site.org'+relative
    console.log(newLink);
```

Comment: all of the menu links are `menu1`  `menu2` etc. on d1, which makes them `d1.site.org/menu1` etc. but when they are on d2, they are  `d2.site.org/menu1`, and I want them to be `d1.site.org/menu1`

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this using ajax. You'll need to process the returned data to update the links.

Comment: I'm using jquery (see title :-) but I was thinking the same thing - need to update the baseURI as the links are being pulled in via the load() argument. I'm researching that now

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ultimately did on d2.site.org:

```
$('#mainNav').load('https://d1.site.org/ header');
$(window).on("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('header nav').each(function() {
            var origUrl = this.href;
            origUrl = origUrl.replace("https://d2.site.org", "");
            var newUrl = 'https://d1.site.org' + origUrl;
            this.href = newUrl;
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Load the main header, then after the page is loaded, wait 1 second, then update all the links that point to d2 and make them point to d1. The reason for the setTimeout is that I couldn't figure out how to do two load events and have the one happen after the other. I could probably also wait less than a second, but it's fast enough for humans who might mouse over those links after the page loads. There's probably other tweaks that could make this better, but it's good enough for now.

Lastly, because the DOM provides the d2.site.org before anything else can get to it, the script has to run afterwards. I don't know of a way to catch the URL attribute as the page is being built.

Comment: You can simplify that by using your newUrl as the replacement string instead of an empty one followed by the concatenation.